# Loop through items created by datatemplate by a listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, datatemplate

In my wpf project I'm using a datatemplate (which consists of a textblock) as an itemtemplate to my listbox. The itemsource is a List of which there are 6 items. How can I loop through the 6 textblock's that are created at runtime?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to access the controls?  Wouldn't you be able to modify them as required using binding against the data source?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by looping over those textblocks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do **not** do it.

Bind everything you need to change to your items and then just change the bound properties, messing with template controls is never a good idea, especially with virtualizing items controls where they may not even exist for all items.

*(What you should not use: `ItemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator.`[`ContainerFromItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemcontainergenerator.containerfromitem.aspx))*

Comment: A few years late ... ;-) Do not do it? What if I need to check against properties that the items in the collection has? So, lets say I have 10 rectangles that was dynamically added. When I move my mouse, I need to find the closest rectangle, and "snap" to to that rect. How is that possible if I cannot iterate through the items?

Comment: @Ted: Your bound data should contain everything, dimensions, location, whatever you need. The only thing that has to involve the view in that example is the mouse event that has to be handled, other than that you go straight to the data object list and find the view-model that represents the respective rect.